# save checked items from CheckedListBox selected Items to .txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm new to c# and windows form application.
i want to save to save selected items from checkedlistbox to a .txt file if not exist then create, if exist then append.

here's how i bind the data to my checkedlistbox, i'm not sure if this is the right way, or there's another way to add value to checkedboxlist.

```
public void bind_clbDepartment()
    {
        DataSet ds = DataBank3.get_department();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
        {
            clbDepartment.Items.Add(drow["id_dept"] + ":" + drow["name_dept"]);
        }
    }


private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //save selected items from clbDepartment to D:\test.txt
            //create if not exist, append if exist
        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to save the selected value from my checkedlistbox to a .txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file) article says you've got a few options

To write an array of strings to a file do this

```
string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);
```

To write a single string do this

```
string text = "A class is the most powerful data type in C#. Like a structure, a class defines the data and behavior of the data type.";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", text);
```

To selective write strings in an array do this

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // If the line doesn't contain the word 'Second', write the line to the file.
                if (!line.Contains("Second"))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

To append a line to the end of an existing file do this

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
    new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt", true))
{
    file.WriteLine("Fourth line");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

Add this `using` at the beginning of you class code:

```
using System.IO;
```

And add this code where you want to write the selected checkboxes' values to your file:

```
string path = "<path to file>";

foreach (ListItem item in clbDepartment.CheckBoxes.Items)
   if (item.Selected)
      File.AppendAllText(path, item.Value);
```